# Amazon EC2 Instance: local ssh tunnel refused by server - Connection failed - [Connection timed out]

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, ssh-tunnel, plink

I have a remote administration tool and I'm trying connect client PC to remote PC through an ssh tunnel (local port forwarding) with an Amazon Instance EC2. I receive this error message from Plink, after several attempts to connect (because the connection not is established initially):

> Forwarded connection refused by server: **Connect failed** [**Connection timed out**]

Here is how i'm logging in (to tunnel) via Plink.exe:

```
plink.exe -v -ssh -2 -P 22 -C -l root -pw mypass -N -L 4021:myhostname.forgot.his.name:4004 root@amazonserver
```

- I'm able to connect in normal ssh.
- On Amazon Instance, Inbound range already is defined to maximum allowed 0-65535.
- *ddclient* is running and working correctly (ping shows the IP of the instance).
- The remote PC also has all ports opened on firewall/modem via DMZ (the connection works without an ssh tunnel).

Does anyone have any idea how solve this "enigma"?

Comment: [The trouble is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSh0U.png)

Comment: `connection timeout` usually points toward a firewall problem.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, then in this case is the firewall of my instance?

Comment: We have no way of knowing that. We also have no way of knowing your configuration from your vague description.